# TableViewCell don't reuse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use "Self Sizing Cells" in my tableview,when insert cell use 'insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:'  cells will be dealloc sometime,but I have set reuseIdentifier for the cells. when I scroll the tableview, cells don't be dealloc.

why for this?

it's code I get cells:

```
Class cls = [CWNSessionUtil cellClassForContent:content];
        NSString *reuseIdentifier = [cls reuseIdentifier];

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if(!cell)
        {
            cell = [[cls alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        }


+(Class)cellClassForContent:(id)content{
    Class cls;

    if([content isKindOfClass:[MessageEntity class]])
    {
        CubeMessageType type = [((MessageEntity *)content) type];
        switch (type) {
            case CubeMessageTypeFile:
                cls = [CWNFileMessageCell class];
                break;
            case CubeMessageTypeImage:
                cls = [CWNImageMessageCell class];
                break;
            case CubeMessageTypeVideoClip:
                cls = [CWNVideoMessageCell class];
                break;
            case CubeMessageTypeVoiceClip:
                cls = [CWNAudioMessageCell class];
                break;
            case CubeMessageTypeCustom:
                cls = [self cellClassForCustomMessage:content];
                break;
            default:
                cls = [CWNTextMessageCell class];
                break;
        }

    }
    else if([content isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        cls = [CWNTipCell class];
    }
    else if([content isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        cls = [CWNTimeCell class];
    }
    else
    {
        cls = [CWNTipCell class];
    }

    return cls;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. Where does that code come from? Is that your `cellForRowAtindexPath` method? Edit your question to show the entire `cellForRowAtindexPath` method, as well as your `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method.

Comment: And you need to explain what that line `Class cls = [CWNSessionUtil cellClassForContent:content];' is and how it fits in.

Comment: and maybe elaborate on what your problem really is. If you are just afraid of retain cycle, then you have nothing to worry about, see my answer. If you want to do something special when the cell get reused, see `prepareForReuse` as LGP suggested. If there is something else you worry about, then give us some context.

Comment: It *sounds* like he's seeing his cells get deallocated sometimes, which is strange, since they should be put into the reuse queue as long as the table view is still around. We need a better explanation though, since it's hard to give meaningful answers based on "it sounds like."

Comment: well, first of all, the `if(!cell)` is suspicious.. in Swift `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` does not return an optional, thus I would expect that would never happen. But `Class cls = [CWNSessionUtil cellClassForContent:content];` might have something with it, and then he is creating the cell manually, and if that happens, that would explain why sometimes they get deallocated - he created them manually.

Comment: I User "[CWNSessionUtil cellClassForContent:content]" to get Appropriate Cell for the content, because I have various cell for different content. not all cell need be use at same time.

Comment: is `if(!cell)` ever evaluated to true? is there any case in which you manually create the cell and not dequeue it? moreover, try to explain what is your problem - as I explained in my answer, it is expected that the reused cells will not get deallocated while the tableView exists..

Answer (score 2):

Reusing means that when the cell goes away from the screen, it won't be deallocated, but the tableView will keep it to use it for those rows that will be presented. Therefore when you dequeue a cell, instead of instantiating a new cell instance, the existing one that is no longer presented on screen is returned. That gives better performance, because the object creation is quite a demanding operation.

Moreover, if you use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` instead of `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`, you can get even better performance, because then in some cases the cell doesn't even have to be redrawn.

Moral of the story: **they do not get deallocated, because you want them to be reused. And for reuse they have to exist. You don't have to worry about retain cycle.**

P.S.: If the problem is that you want to be notified when the cell goes into reuse queue (so it waits to be reused), use `prepareForReuse` as LGP suggested. That can be used in case when a cell does some heavy weight operation but it goes off screen, so you can cancel the operation to release resources as soon as possible.

However, in most cases you can configure the cell from the scratch in the `cellForRow` - just remember that unless you cleared the cell's content in `prepareForReuse`, you have to make sure that you reset all the contents. E.g., if you have a label showing an optional string, then when reused in the new row without this string, the label will be set to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

As had been said the cells are not deallocated when reused. To perform cleanup in the reused cell there is another method available for `UITableViewCell` objects that can be used, called `-(void)prepareForReuse;` that will be called just before the cell is returned from the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method.

Don't forget to call the superclass method if you override `prepareForReuse` method.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse?language=objc